# Showing a mySQL entry by clicking on a link

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I've got one site which should be like a list of contents. The topics are saved in a mySQL database. If you click on a topic it should open a new site. The only difference between those sites is the text which is also saved in that database.

How can I realize that without writing hundreds of sites?

Example:

`--page1.php--        --page2.php-----
 |Topic1     |        |Database entry|
 |Topic2 ----|-Click->|with title    |
 |Topic3 -,  |        |"Topic2"      |
 ---------|---        ----------------
          |
         Click
          |
         \/
 --page2.php-----
 |Database entry|
 |with title    |
 |"Topic3"      |
 ----------------`

If you click "Topic2" page2.php opens containing the Database entry of "Topic2", if you click another topic, the same page opens but it contains a different entry.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the unique identifier of the topic by a GET parameter in the URL.